# Server freeze on PHP session_start (multiple sites on same domain)

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am having a problem with **session_start()** when executed from the server itself.

The whole problem is that I have a WordPress and eShop. Both working on the same domain and having the same session. When I go from eShop to WordPress the session is available, but I need to load few components from eShop to be loaded in WordPress.

Since there is Smarty engine on eShop I need to get the template via **file_get_contents** and since its not a request, I need to specify the session ID for the eShop to recognize me.

But when I call the function with specified ID, the request simply freezes, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the security handler. When I fetched the session ID to eShop, it had to create a new session with specified ID, but the session was still opened by WordPress which lead to filelock and freeze on the server when trying to access the session file in eShop.

So I worked the following solution: You need to close the session file so eShop can start using the session file by using **session_write_close**.

```
<?php
    // close session file
    session_write_close();
    // build the request url with session_id
    $load_basket = $this->_eshop_url .'&force_session='.session_id();
    // fetch the output of eShop template
    echo file_get_contents($load_basket);
?>
```